# route и параметры

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

У меня имеется метод который принимает 3 параметра

```
[Route("api/calculator/{operation}/{fvalue}/{svalue}")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(string operation, string fvalue, string svalue)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, string.Format("Result:" + CalculatorManager.Operation(operation, Double.Parse(fvalue), Double.Parse(svalue))));
}
```

При вызывании API нету никаких проблем если вызывать

> http://localhost:50462/api/calculator/Add/1/1

Но если сделать таким образом

> http://localhost:50462/api/calculator/?operation=Add&fvalue=1&svalue=1

Я так понимаю, что если использовать Route то больше нельзя задавать параметры, просто я хочу сделать микс, но не могу найти ответ как.

Comment: что если повесить на метод 2 маршрута?

Comment: [Route("api/calculator/{operation}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(string operation,[FromBody]Models.Operation modelOperation, string fvalue = null, string svalue = null) пришел к такому решению